# Ruby 2 dimensional array finding max value and sort array

Tags: ruby

I have an array of arrays with coordinates which represent a polyline:

```
array = [
  [3004.9999999999986, -500.0],
  [5733.5, -500.0],
  [5733.5, 300.0],
  [8462.0, 300.0],
  [8462.0, 1026.163313244362],
  [7254.568694406579, 1026.163313244362],
  [7254.568694406579, 1500.0],
  [3004.9999999999914, 1500.0],
  [3004.9999999999914, 1224.9602566586254],
  [5.0, 1224.9602566586254],
  [5.00000000000015, 300.0],
  [3004.9999999999986, 300.0]
]
```

I have to find the coordinate with the lowest x-value and highest y-value where a lower x-value has priority over a higher y-value.

For the above array the expected result is as follows (lowest x and then highest y):

```
[5.0, 1224.9602566586254]
```

Comment: “I have to find the coordinate ...”—So what?

Comment: Construct a sample array and show the desired output so we can help you

Comment: @mudasobwa Matz is nice!

Comment: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I understand that OP is at mistake by not reading it Andrey, but what happened to the empathy of experienced people.

Comment: @biervat "... has priority over ..." means, that the y-value must be checked only when multiple rows have lowest x-value?

Comment: Your example has a single lowest `x` value. Could you show an example that also takes `y` into account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#`min_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by):

```
array.min_by { |x, y| [x, -y] }
#=> [5.0, 1224.9602566586254]
```

or [Enumerable#`max_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by):

```
array.max_by { |x, y| [-x, y] }
#=> [5.0, 1224.9602566586254]
```

Comment: I was trying with min_by but i couldn't get the largest y value. Thanks for this simple solution.

Comment: How can I change the priority? For example I want the highest y and then the lowest x. For the above array the expected result is: `[3004.9999999999914, 1500.0]`

Comment: @biervat `a.max_by { |x,y| [y, -x] }` => `[3004.9999999999914, 1500.0]`. Please, make sure to accept the answer if that solved your issue (look for a checkmark near the answer score)